# Is processing a large 3d array with anywhere from 100 to 100 instructions per array row a good problem to be solved on the GPU?

Tags: java, gpu, gpgpu

I have a problem where I need to run a complex function on a large 3d array. For each array row, I will execute anywhere from 100 to 1000 instructions, and depending on the data on that row some instructions will or not be executed.

This array is large but would still fit inside a GPU shared memory (around 2GB in size). I could execute these instructions on separate parts of the array given that they don't need to be processed in order, so I'm thinking executing on the GPU could be a good option. I'm not entirely sure because the instructions executed will change depending on the data itself (lots of if/then/else in there) and I've read branching could an issue.

These instructions are an abstract syntax tree representing a short program that operates over the array row and returns a value.

Does this look like an appropriate problem to be tackled by the GPU?

What other info would be needed to determine that?

I'm thinking to write this in Java and use JCuda.

Thanks!

Eduardo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It Depends. How big is your array, i.e. how many parallel tasks does your array provide (in your case it sounds like the number of rows is the number of parallel tasks you're going to execute)? If you have few rows (ASTs) but many columns (commands), then maybe it's not worth it. The other way round would work better, because more work can be parallelized.

Branching can indeed be an issue if you're unaware. You can do some optimizations though to mitigate that cost - after you got your initial prototype running and can do some comparision measurements.

The issue with Branching is, that all streaming multiprocessors in one "Block" need to execute the same instruction. If one core does not need that instruction, it sleeps. So if you have two ASTs, each with 100 distinct commands, the multiprocessors will take 200 commands to complete the calculation, some of the SMs will be sleeping while the other do their commands.

If you have 1000 commands max and some only use a subset, the processor will take as many commands as the AST with the most commands has - in the optimal case. E.g. a set of (100, 240, 320, 1, 990) will run for at least 990 commands, even though one of the ASTs only uses one command. And if that command isn't in the set of 990 commands from the last AST, it even runs for 991 commands.

You can mitigate this (after you have the prototype working and can do actual measurements) by optimizing the array you send to the GPU, so that one set of Streaming Multiprocessors (Block) has a similar set of instructions to do. As different SMs don't interfere with each other on the execution level, they don't need to wait on each other. The size of the blocks is also configurable when you execute the code, so you can adjust it somewhat here.

For even more optimization - only 32 (NVidia "Warp")/64 (AMD "Wavefront") of the threads in a block are executed at the same time, so if you organize your array to exploit this, you can even gain a bit more.

How much of a difference those optimizations make is dependant on how sparse / dense / mixed your command array will be. Also not all optimizations actually optimize your execution time. Testing and comparing is key here. Another source of optimization is your memory layout, but with your described use case it shouldn't be a problem. You can look up [Memory Coalescing](https://cvw.cac.cornell.edu/GPU/coalesced) for more info on that.

Comment: That's fantastic!! Thank you very much for all this info - very useful!